# HOWTO: Rollback on Oracle (ODP.NET) and SqlCe bulk operation failure

Tags: oracle, sql-server-ce, bulkinsert, rollback, sqlbulkcopy

I would like to know how to:

1) rollback an oracle (odp.net) and sqlce bulk operation (insert, update, delete) if it has failed for some reason. I do not know If bulk operations (oracle and sqlce) do rollback automatically internally on any failure.

2) In oracle, in case of OracleBulkCopy, I know it is possible to define transaction for a batch (not per record) by setting OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction as a parameter in the OracleBulkCopy constructor which means that each batch of the bulk copy operation occurs within a transaction and on failure the batch is rollbacked, but my doubt here is:  What happens if for example, some batches go ok and one fails? those batches ok are not rolled back but the one has failed is, so in this case how to rollback all the changes (those batches ok and those not ok)?

Comment: If you'r not sure disable auto commit and explicitly rollback on exception.

Comment: @haki Could you post an example?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific thing your are asking about just with how general odbc access works.